# Calculate how many blocks of n minutes between two times

Tags: php, math

I have a web application that I am designing. It will allow admins to dynamically set a "Block Size" for appointments, as well as "Opening Hours".

Now I need a way to dynamically calculate the number of "Blocks" between the "Opening Hours".

i.e. block_size = 30 (minutes). How many 30 minute blocks between 9:00 and 17:00

OR

block_size = 60 (minutes). How many 60 minute blocks between 8:00 and 18:00

OR

Any combination of time and block size

Comment: You mean, floor((endTime-startTime)/block_size) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
<?php
$seconds = $blocksize * 60; // get the seconds of the blocksize
$start = strtotime("$open"); // get epoch time
$end = strtotime("$close"); // get epoch time
$math = $end - $start; // in epoch time
$blocks = $math / $seconds;

echo 'result: '.$blocks;
?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: $blocksize is given by him 30 or 60 like that

Comment: if $blocksize is 10 then what happens. $blocksize may have any value

Comment: @syed mohamed Thank you. Almost the same. I'm usually slower than everyone else at answering because I always test my code before posting it. That, of course, slows me down a bit in giving my answers. I'm not saying you don't test as well. No offense. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with DatePeriod:

```
$start = new DateTime('9:00');
$end = new DateTime('17:00');
$blockDuration = new DateInterval('PT30M')
$blocks = new DatePeriod($start, $blockDuration, $end);
echo count(iterator_to_array($blocks)); // 16
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$start = strtotime("start time");
$end = strtotime("end time");
$elapsed = $end - $start;
$min = date("i", $elapsed);
$blocks = floor($min/block_size);
echo $blocks;
?>
```